# QGIS multiply(add) two raster but divide(deduct) another raster

Tags: qgis, raster, overlay

I am making a parking analysis in one town. I need to obatin the zones where the parking of car is harder because there is less places to park and higher demand of cars.I have three rasters.

First raster represents the number of PUBLIC car parking places in a town (the redder the more parking places):

[image]

Second raster represents the number of PRIVATE car parking places in a town (the redder the more parking places):

[image]

I need to add (multiply) these two layers. To do so, in blending mode i select Multiply in both layers, and i get:

[image]

Which looks great. I'll call the union of these two layers A from now on.

The problem comes when a third layer comes into action, B from now on. 
This third layer represents the vehicles in the census of the town, which is, the demand of car parking places:

[image]

What i think i need to achieve is B-A so that the places with high park demand (many vehicles in the census) in B, are lightened by A.

I don't know if I explained myself.

Regards,

Comment: Have you tried QGIS "Raster Calculator"? Here you can do image algebra.

Comment: no, i haven't, i think this could be the solution to my question, can you please write a suitable answer so i can mark it as valid?